# What is a loan creation?

Tags: historical-linguistics, orthography, borrowing

How is it different from a loanword? One example given was *mitkind* created on stimulus of English sibling. Does this mean *mitkind* is a new word but with a foreign sense? Is there such thing as loaning a sense?

Comment: Is it another term for a calque?

Comment: Can you [edit] this to provide a quote of it being used?

Comment: Which language are you asking about? German?

Comment: So, *mitkind* is based on an English word but not an English loan? No *from English* in the etymology? How is it different to English just picking up Greek and French words to use as new words?

Answer (score 6):

The original German term was *Lehnschöpfung* that was calqued into English.

There are three beasts to distinguish here:

- The loan word (German *Lehnwort*) that is directly borrowed from the donor language with minor adaptions to the target language
- The calque (German *Lehnübersetzung*) that is formed from morphemes in the target language following a model in the donor language (example: German Aus-stellung from Latin ex-positio)
- The loan creation (German *Lehnschöpfung*) is a new word in the target language filling a perceived semantic gap triggered by a donor language. The way that word is formed has no relation to the donor language. Yiddish *mitkind* is a great example, other classical examples are newly introduced religious terminology after the adoption of a new religion (typically Christianity).

P.S. A really well written and even more detailed answer can be found here: https://www.quora.com/Concerning-German-linguistic-terminology-what-are-the-differences-and-relations-among-Entlehnung-Lehnpr%C3%A4gung-Lehnbedeutung-Lehnbildung-Lehn%C3%BCbersetzung-Lehn%C3%BCbertragung-Lehnsch%C3%B6pfung-and-Scheinentlehnung

Comment: What is entlehnt about a Lehnschöpfung?

Comment: @fdb The fact that there is now a one-to-one translation for a certain foreign word where previously a circumlocution or the insertion of a foreign word was necessary.

Comment: That assumes that Yiddish "mitkind" is based on English.

Comment: In English, "sibling" died out in the 15th century  and was reintroduced in the 20th century as a technical term in anthropology.

Comment: @fdb Interesting! I did not know that before, given how common and natural the word sibling sounds nowadays.

Comment: I can't find any reference for "mitkind". My Yiddish dictionary only has "geshvester".

Comment: Hmm... the example wasn't made-up by me, and I think it goes back to  Werner Betz (who coined the term *Lehnschöpfung*)