# Loanwords with different meanings from original language?

Tags: terminology, borrowing

First, let me say this questions is asking only about fairly recent loanwords (as in, the word (or something similar to it) exists in both languages). I'm not asking about very old loanwords that may have shifted in meaning in either/both languages.

As an example of what kind of loanwords I'm looking for, let me present:

`das Handy` and `der Smoking` in German (borrowed from English; try to guess the meaning before looking at the spoiler below).

> `cellphone` and `tuxedo`, respectively.

Even though both are "borrowed" from English, the meaning probably isn't clear to an English speaker.

I am **not** referring just to loanwords where the meaning is slightly adjusted from the meaning in the borrowing language, for example:

- `sombrero` ("hat" in Spanish, but a specific style of hat when borrowed into English).
- `baguette` (I guess "rod" or "wand" would be the best translation? Also refers to the bread, because it has that shape. In English, refers exclusively to the bread.)

Is there a term for loanwords with a completely different meaning in the borrowing language (to the point that native speakers of the original language wouldn't understand)? Can anyone think of examples where English borrowed a word and did this? (I have trouble with this as an English speaker.) I do realise this might be fairly subjective.

If I've screwed up any terms, please let me know and I can edit this.

Comment: When a word is borrowed, liberties are taken with its pronunciation (consider Germans discussing _Jazz_) and with its meaning, since the borrowing happens in particular circumstances and contexts, where the meaning is specific and limited. If these circumstances recur, so can the borrowing, and so can the changes.

Comment: See also this question and its answers: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/29471/what-is-a-loan-creation

Comment: Would you include cases like _double entendre_, which looks French, but doesn’t actually exist in French at all? Also, _Smoking_ is not as illogical as you might think: the tuxedo or dinner jacket evolved out of the smoking jacket and was called a smoking jacket for a while in English too – that’s the usage that stuck in several other languages.

Comment: US/GB _football_ = rugby/soccer (prescriptive terms, different cultures). German _Parking_ (different usage).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm aware of _why_ it's called a Smoking in German, but it's not a way that it would be used in English, and it's probably not clear to English speakers.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso My point was that it can be difficult to draw the line between a ‘fairly recent’ loan and a ‘very old’ loan where the meanings have drifted over time. With _Smoking_, the English meaning **has** drifted over time since the word was borrowed into German, even if the loan isn’t actually all that old, so isn’t it really an example of one of the things you start out by excluding? I can think of no loan words that _start out_ being unintelligible to speakers of the source language; that usually only happens after mismatched semantic shifts.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ok fair enough. I admit that it's fairly difficult to draw a clear line on these sorts of things. I guess that explains why there's not a nice word for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In German a word like *Handy* or *Oldtimer* can be called a *Scheinanglizismus* (**pseudo-Anglicism**).

Of course that is specific to this one source language, and there are others for other languages.

More generally it can be called a *Scheinentlehnung* (pseudo-loan).

*Smoking* is a bit different because it is similar in many languages, so it's not clear that German speakers invented it.

There is another word *false friend* (or similar in other languages) which is for a broader category, like *actual*.

Not all possible sets have a shorthand label with currency in every language.

Comment: I wasn't aware other languages had something similar to _Smoking_, thanks. It's unfortunate that there's no specific word  for this, besides _pseudo-<language>ism_

Comment: Maybe *pseudo-loan*?

Comment: You can use the German term *Scheinentlehnung* (at least in a scholarly paper)

Comment: Yes, thank you, updated.

Comment: @vectory Every German knows that *Handy* comes from the Swabian dialect question *Hän die koi Schur?* "Do they have no wire?"

Answer (score 1):

Most loanwords develop different meanings, so the term *is* a loanword/borrowing. You should just assume that the loan could have a different meaning from the source language.