# Examples for calque / loan-translation words with different meanings in different languages

Tags: translation, borrowing, meaning, calques

Are there words/phrases/compound-words in two different languages that use the same words in their respective languages (like a calque / loan translation) but result in different meanings?

Here is a made up example if my question isn't clear:

> [English] Lady Bird meaning A small beetle.

> [Some other Language] XY (X = Lady, Y = Bug) which should have a meaning different from the beetle (Maybe something like a lady who is irritating just to give you an example).

I know that calques have the same meaning in both languages for example: Superman and Übermensch means almost the same thing in English and German but here I am specifically looking for words that seem like calques / loan translations but differ in their meanings.

I wasn't able to find any questions here on the topic.
[Loanwords with different meanings from original language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31980/loanwords-with-different-meanings-from-original-language)
This is the closest I can find but it is a question on loanwords that diverged from their original meanings.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Seems like you're asking for *false friends* with some constraints (e.g. that they be compounds, that they share etymology).

Comment: Would *Unternehmer* vs *undertaker* qualify?  (Let's assume it's not a calque.)

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Yeah I want them to be calque-like. As in - It needs to share the component words in their respective languages but at the same time have different meanings.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Yes, _Unternehmer_ and _Undertaker_ seem to me as a correct example! (I don't know German but I googled) Looks like It means Entrepreneur in German which is a complete different meaning from the English _Undertaker_ . Are there more examples? Is there a name for words like these?

Comment: You can look for lists of **false friends** (like https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:False_cognates_and_false_friends), and then filter for those that fit your criteria.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Thanks for the link, I will look through. Also I just looked up https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undertaker and looks like _Undertaker_ does have a meaning of Entrepreneur in English. So I think I am wrong to say that it is a correct example. Please let me know if you find anything else!

Comment: @Tangent I wouldn't say you were wrong. If someone told me they were "an undertaker", I would not assume they were an entrepreneur - that's what entrepreneur is for. In contrast, someone who undertakes is more likely to be an entrepreneur than an undertaker - which is probably where that extra definition you found comes from.

Answer (score 1):

**1. False friends**

As per [good suggestion from Adam Bittlingmayer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38520/examples-for-calque-loan-translation-words-with-different-meanings-in-differen#comment88675_38520) you can look at false friends. Russian is a particular example of the language, where Proto-Indo-European roots evolved differently to Germanic and Romance languages.

For example:

English: *beryl fabric* (meaning: a cloth of beryl color)

Russian: *берилловая фабрика* (meaning: chemical manufacturing plant specialized on beryl compounds)

I believe in most European languages you will also get a calque with the latter meaning.

**2. Calqued [auto-antonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym)**

*Presidential sanction* could mean approval or disapproval from President in English. Calqued version will also sound almost identical in most European languages and could go either way.

**Upd.**

By combining the two, you can even make sentences which sound almost the same, but have different meaning. This example may sound a bit machine-generated, but I believe it has meaning and is grammatically correct:

English: *Director of marketing on the phone insulted and sanctioned a magazine of beryl fabrics.*

Russian: *Директор по маркетингу на фоне инсульта санкционировал магазин берилловой фабрики.* (meaning: Director of marketing, in the midst of a stroke, authorized a beryl factory store.)

Comment: The cognates of *fabric* mean factory in every single European language except English, as far as I am aware.  That's an example of how English evolved to be unique, not Russian.