# Is there a term for a word taken from another language, but then completely changing the meaning (such as peperoni, latte, chai)

Tags: terminology, etymology, borrowing

In Italian, *il peperone* is what the English would call *bell pepper*, but the English word *peperoni* has come to mean a type of sausage, in particular when on a pizza.

In Italian, *latte* is milk, but in English and several other languages, *latte* has come to mean a type of *coffee* with milk.

In English, *chai* is short for *masala chai*, a type of Indian tea with sweet spices, but the word *chai* sounds (very) similar to Russian [*чай*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9#Russian), Hindi [*चाय*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF#Hindi), Persian [*چای*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%DA%86%D8%A7%DB%8C#Persian), or Mandarin [*茶*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%8C%B6#Mandarin), which all just mean tea.

All of the above have the potential to confuse people who speak one language but not the other.

Is there a word for this type of etymological journey, in which a word is taken from another language but given a quite different meaning?

Comment: _Le smoking_, _le rosbif_, _sportif_, _le five o'clock_

Comment: See also this question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/31980/9781

Comment: Virtually every borrowed word has a different meaning or reference in the borrowing language from the meaning it had or has in the source language. It's unavoidable; native names have all sorts of associations that are stripped off by borrowing and replaced by new ones and new metaphors and strange expectations in a new culture.

Answer (score 1):

The closest term I can think of is "[false friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend#Homonyms)" (informal) or "bilingual homophones" (formal), they can either derive from loanwords (taken from a different language then developed to a new meaning), or from shared etymology.

Comment: Hmm, but the examples I gave are rather direct paths of loanwords becoming false friends, which does not apply to all false friends.

Comment: Note that all of the examples have changed from words referring to one kind of food/drink to words referring to a different type. Not really "completely changed".